# Assessing which person is the one with the next birthday

Tags: date, stata

In Stata I am trying to assess which of the given birthdays is the next one compared with a given date. My data looks like this:

- All dates are in daily format (%dD_m_Y), e.g. 18mar1926
- Variable `date` which is the reference date with which all other dates should be compared
- Variables `birth1, birth2, birth3, birth4, birth5, birth6` contain the birthday of all possible household members.

For example: A household with two adults A and B. The birthday of A is 20th Nov 1977 and the birthday of person B is 30th March 1978. The reference date is 29.11.2020. I want to know who is the person who has the next birthday, in the example above it is person B, because person A has had its birthday one week before the reference date, so the next birthday in this household will be celebrated on the 30 March 2021.

Example data:

| date | birth1 | birth2 | birth3 | birth4 | birth5 | birth6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02feb2021 | 15jan1974 | 27nov1985 |  |  |  |  |
| 30nov2020 | 31aug1945 | 27jun1999 | 07apr1997 |  |  |  |
| 19nov2020 | 27sep1993 | 30dec1996 |  |  |  |  |
| 29jan2021 | 29mar1973 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 05dec2020 | 21jan1976 | 02oct1976 | 21jan1976 | 25may1995 | 15feb1997 |  |
| 25nov2020 | 25nov1943 | 29nov1946 |  |  |  |  |
| 02feb2021 | 28apr1979 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: See https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew16 for relevant functions added to Stata 16 on 5 Nov 2020. `nextbirthday()` sounds exactly right.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no Stata 16 version available, only 15.1

Comment: Edited answer to handle February 29 birthdays as though they were March 1st when `date` is in a non-leap year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED to account for Feb 29**

**The edit will treat people who have a February 29 birthday as if it were March 1 in cases when the year of `date` is not a leap year. If that doesn't make sense for your particular use case, it should be easy to alter the code below as you see fit.*

Since you want the next birthday in the year rather than the closest birthday, you can use the year of `date` and the month and day from `birth{i}` to create a date for each person's next birthday. Then you can sinmply take the earliest value from each household. I reshape long, and generate a person and household `id` in order to do this.

**Make example data**

```
clear
set obs 6
set seed 1996
generate date = floor((mdy(12,31,2020)-mdy(12,1,2015)+1)*runiform() + mdy(12,1,2015))
format date %td

forvalue i = 1/6 {
    gen birth`i' = floor((mdy(12,31,1996)-mdy(12,1,1980)+1)*runiform() + mdy(12,1,1980)) if _n < `i' == 0
    format birth`i'  %td
}

replace birth6 = birth4 in 6 // want a tie
replace birth2 = date("29feb1996","DMY") in 3 // Feb 29
```

**Find Next Birthday**

```
gen household_id = _n
reshape long birth, i(date household_id) j(person)
drop if mi(birth)

gen person_next_birthday = mdy( month(birth), day(birth), year(date))
* TREAT FEB 29 as if they have a march 1 birthday in non-leap years
replace person_next_birthday = mdy(3,1,year(date)) if month(birth) == 2 ///
& day(birth) == 29 & mod(year(date),4)!=0
replace person_next_birthday = mdy( month(birth), day(birth), year(date) + 1) if person_next_birthday < date 
replace person_next_birthday = mdy(3,1,year(date)+1) if month(birth) == 2 ///
& day(birth) == 29 & mod(year(date) + 1,4)!=0 & person_next_birthday < date
format person_next_birthday  %td

bysort household_id  (person_next_birthday): gen next_bday = person_next_birthday[1]
format next_bday %td
drop person_next_birthday

reshape wide birth, i(date household_id next_bday) j(person)

gen next_bday_persons = ""
* Make a string to present household persons who have next bday
foreach v of varlist birth* {
    local person = subinstr("`v'","birth","",.)
    local condition = "month(`v') == month(next_bday) & day(`v') == day(next_bday)"
    local condition_feb29 = "month(next_bday) == 3 & day(next_bday) == 1 & month(`v') == 2 & day(`v') == 29"
    replace next_bday_persons = next_bday_persons + "|`person'" if `condition' | `condition_feb29'
}
replace next_bday_persons = regexr(next_bday_persons,"^\|","")
order next_bday_persons, after(next_bday)
```

The last loop is unnecessary, but illustrates that this is robust to ties.

Comment: Looks very careful. Irritating awkward comment: does this cope with birthdays on 29 February?

Comment: Good catch, thank you! I anticipated that Stata would push the date to March 1 which I now realize it does not. I will post an edit for OP shortly, some condition on `mod(year(date),4)` should do the trick.

Comment: I wrote something on calculating people's ages that was a complete pain, once you try to catch different kinds of input and scope for different ages as output (completed years, or fractional years, or years and days). The start of age = present date minus birthday is only a start.